# How are Linux kernel compile config's determined?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I am compiling my first Kernel (3.5 rc1) from source through `menuconfig`.

Certain configuration options are pre-set.

- Who / what determines if they are pre-set?
- Does the `make menuconfig` somehow detect my computer and its devices and characteristics and generates them?
- Or do the default configs come with the source, pre-determined by someone (who put the source out)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`make menuconfig` doesn't dynamically determine your environment and tries to set the appropriate config but uses your `.config` file and the default entries in [kconfig](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt).

So yes the defaults come with the source and are specified in the [kconfig](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt) files which also specify the help text, dependencies and other things. Have a look at a sample kconfig file like [net/Kconfig](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/Kconfig).

[`make localmodconfig`](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Good-and-quick-kernel-configuration-creation-1403046.html) on the other hand tries to create a custom tailored kernel configuration for your system based on the loaded modules. It takes your current configuration (typically from your distribution) and will only enable the loaded modules.

Comment: Loaded modules are (by default) determined by the output of `lsmod`.